# How to extract just the characters "abc-3456" from the given text in python

Tags: python

i have this code

```
import re   

text = "this is my desc abc-3456"
m = re.findall("\w+\\-\d+", text)
print m
```

This prints ['abc-3456'] but i want to get only abc-3456 (without the square brackets and the quotes].
How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to get substrings of that format, or do you just want to get the last space-delimited substring? ... Oh, uh.. never mind. I wasn't paying attention; you've already got the regex there :).

Comment: `m = re.findall("\w+\\-\d+", text)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re   

text = "this is my desc abc-3456"
m = re.findall("\w+\\-\d+", text)
print m[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>   Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

`findall` returns list of strings. If you want the first one then use `m[0]`.
`print m[0]` will give string without `[]` and `''`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first (or only) result, do this:

```
import re

text = "this is my desc abc-3456"
m = re.search("\w+\\-\d+", text)
print m.group()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) retuns a **list** of matches. In that list the result is a **string**. You can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) if you want.

In python, a list's representation is in brackets: `[member1, member2, ...]`.

A string ("somestring") representation is in quotes: `'somestring'`.

This means the representation of a list of strings is:

```
['somestring1', 'somestring2', ...]
```

So you have a string in a list, the characters you want to remove are a part of python's representation and not a part of the data you have.

To get the string simply take the first element from the list:

```
mystring = m[0]
```